# Blog comment moderation rules

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, blog

Since my profile will be deleted in a few hours, this doesn't concern me, but the remaining people may be interested.

We know the already famous post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1. One may be surprised that it has too few comments, especially highly negative ones. It seems that the reason is simple: moderation. About 4 hours ago I've written the comment there, but it wasn't published. Since I don't see it "awaiting moderation" anymore and I see much later comments published, it seems to be removed. The comment was along these lines:

> There were a lot of things I didn't like in SO: too positively-skewed
>   reputation changes, generally-accepted reputation farming via
>   answering duplicates which were asked 10 times, extremely low quality
>   threshold for questions, "accepted answer" feature implementation, etc. and etc. Looking at the recent changes,
>   things will become only worse. I'm deleting my profile.

Now, the question is: why was it removed? Is it unfriendly? Sure, but I don't see why it should be friendly: we express our opinions, and my opinion is negative. Is it non-constructive? Well, to some extent, but definitely more constructive than:

> Nice! I’m (hopefully) looking forward to passing the 10k mark

If there are rules for commenting (like 2. You DO NOT TALK bad about SO), I think it makes sense to publish them (and give an easily-found link to them in the blog). It also would be interesting to know how comment moderation is organized.

Comment: I left a comment in a similar vein to yours. It also was not accepted. If you are too critical, they do not want to hear about it.

Comment: They'd never publish a rule saying "no criticism allowed", because that would make them look bad. Instead they'll just silently delete criticism anyway. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: @House-'ReinstateMonica'-man, but actually there are some critical comments (not so critical of course). So I was surprised when my comment wasn't published.

Comment: Imagine instead of 2 critical comments seeing 50 and only 1 positive. That wouldn't be good for their image. Therefore, they censor us with various pretexts.